# Passing anonymous functions as parameters for later use

Tags: javascript

I'm having issues with a script that I made for use in HTML5. 
Here is the function

```
function loadImage(loc,after,para){
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = loc;
        if(typeof(after) != "undefined" && typeof(para) != "undefined"){
            img.onloadeddata  = after(img,para);
        }else if(typeof(after) != "undefined"){
            img.onloadeddata  = after(img);
        }
        return img;
}
```

and here is what is calling it

```
window.globalFriends[i][2]=loadImage('http://graph.facebook.com/'+window.globalFriends[i][0]+'/picture', function (a){
    updateLoaders();
    loadingDrawPerson(a);});
```

What I'm trying to do is send a function as a parameter for it then to be called.
It kinda of works but it a weird way. For example; All the images do get loaded but the onloadeddata either fires the function way to early or the function is getting executed before it gets to the loadImage function.

What are your ideas on my malfunctioning script?

Thank-you for reading
Paul

Comment: `typeof` is an operator, not a function so there is no need for a grouping operator after it. Use: `typeof after`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A line like this:

```
img.onloadeddata  = after(img,para);
```

Means "call the `after` function with arguments `img` and `para`" and assign the result to `onloadeddata`."  If, instead, you're wanting to assign the function to `onloadeddata`, do this:

```
img.onloadeddata = function() { after(img, para); };
```

Answer (score 1):

It's `img.onload` And it needs a function.

Try

```
img.onload = function() {
    after(img, para);
}
```

I think your missing the para parameter

```
window.globalFriends[i][2]=loadImage('http://graph.facebook.com/'+window.globalFriends[i][0]+'/picture', function (a){
    updateLoaders();
    loadingDrawPerson(a);}/*, para */); // <- where is para?
```